# is storing ether in a single contract more gas efficient for a large user base smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to build a smart contract application similar to mainstream betting. I would love to know the best way to store user (betters) stakes for a betting event.

The smart contract has an Event contract that any EOA can create.

Each event can have multiple markets.

Let's say an event can be a football match between **Manchester United and Chelsea**.

A market with this instance can be "**double chance**" or "**3way**";

Each market can have multiple pools.

Pools  with this instance can be "**1X** or **12** or **X2**" or "**1** or **X** or **2**" respectively.

Users can place bets on these pools. On placing bets, A Bet contract is created in the pool contract.

Here is an example of the Bet contract

```
contract Bets is IWeb3BetsBetsV1 {
address public better;

address public eventAddress;

address public marketAddress;

address public poolAddress;

uint256 public stake;

modifier onlyEventOwner {
    IWeb3BetsEventV1 betEvent = IWeb3BetsEventV1(eventAddress);
    require(tx.origin == betEvent.getEventOwner(), "Only bet owners can apply this function");
    
    _;
}

modifier onlyBetter {
    require(tx.origin == better, "Only event better can call this function");
    _;
}

constructor(
    address _eventAddress,
    address _marketAddress,
    address _poolAddress,
    uint256 _stake,
    address _better
) {
    eventAddress = _eventAddress;
    marketAddress = _marketAddress;
    stake = _stake;
    better = _better;
    poolAddress = _poolAddress;
}

function getBetStake() override external view returns (uint256) {
    return stake;
}

function getBetter() override external view returns (address) {
    return better;
}

function getBetPoolAddress() override external view returns (address) {
    return poolAddress;
}

function getBetMarketAddress() override external view returns (address) {
    return marketAddress;
}

function getBetEventAddress() override external view returns (address) {
    return eventAddress;
}


function withdraw() override external payable onlyBetter {
    require(address(this).balance > 0, "This bet has no funds");

    IWeb3BetsEventV1 eventV1 = IWeb3BetsEventV1(eventAddress);
    uint status = eventV1.getEventStatus();

    // its not equal to pending or started
    if (status== 0 && status ==1){
        revert("An event must be cancelled or ended to withdraw funds and earnings");

    }

    IWeb3BetsMarketV1 marketV1 = IWeb3BetsMarketV1(marketAddress);
    bool isWinningPool = marketV1.isWinningPool(poolAddress);
    if (!isWinningPool){
        revert("You lost this bet");
    }
    
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
}

fallback() payable external {}

receive() payable external {}
```

}

I have two options for storing user's bets,

1. Transferring the user's stake (msg.value) to the market contract.
2. Transferring the user's stake to the Bet contract.

I am looking for a better and cost-efficient way to store the user's bet stake.

The contract algorithm for option one gets all addresses of the winning pool in the market and transfers their respective bet earnings to the Bet's contract getBetterAddress() address. This also only runs when the event creator ends the contract and sets the winning pool for each market. But I have doubts when the betters reaches say one thousand. I will have to loop through them and send their earnings to them respectively.

I would really love some help on which could be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

The second option is indeed better. Wherever you can avoid iterating through something, do it.

In fact, you shouldn't iterate through users at all. You should use a Pull over Push design: https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/pull_over_push.html